# Java stream Collectors.groupingBy() with list of String

Tags: java, java-8

I have following class :

```
Class Foo{
  private String cassette;
  private List<String> organs; //["Lung","Liver"]
  //getter setter
}
```

I'm collecting data into `List<Foo>` and I want to group them by **organ** as `Map<String,List<Foo>>`

So far I have tried following solution:

```
Map<Object, List<Foo>> collect = fooList
                                   .stream()
                                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getOrgan()));
```

It returns `Map<Object, List<Foo>>` instead of `Map<String,List<Foo>>` as follow:

> {[Lung, Liver]=[Foo [cassette=1A, organ=[Lung, Liver]]], [Liver]=[Foo
>   [cassette=2A, organ=[Liver]]]}

Also, how can I make a generic method which will return `Map<String,List<Foo>>` when I pass only key for grouping of `Type<T>` for `Collectors.groupingBy(T)` and it will group by a specified key

Comment: Because it's how you declared it: `Map<Object, List<Foo>> collect`

Comment: You are grouping `Map<List<String>, List<Foo>>` as `getOrgans()` returns `List<String>`.

Comment: @KunLun I get compiler error if I make it to `Map<String,List<Foo>>` i.e.`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,List<Foo>> to Map<String,List<Foo>>`

Comment: Perhaps, because `getOrgan()` has been declared to return `Object`. How are we supposed to know…

Comment: @Holger you are right but that's not the point here, the problem is with grouping of `List` which is solved https://stackoverflow.com/a/60300071/10785239 here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are grouping by a `List<String>`, not by a `String`. To group by a `String` you have to pre-process the `Stream` to first obtain all the pairs of (String,Foo):

```
Map<String,List<Foo>> collect = 
    fooList.stream()
           .flatMap(f -> f.getOrgan().stream().map(o -> new SimpleEntry<>(o,f)))
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                          Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                             Collectors.toList())));
```